# 「困っから」、「文句あっか」 dialectal?

Tags: dialects, morphology

> 水分塩分ちゃんと取ってよ 今死なっでも困っから ([source](https://hiroo1969.livedoor.blog/archives/72641804.html))

> アトピーだ、文句あっか。([河野太郎](https://twitter.com/konotarogomame/status/1243160230084538371))

These seem to follow a common pattern: あるか→あっか, 困るから→困っから and I wonder if this is dialectal, and if yes what dialect exactly. 河野太郎 seems to be from 関東/首都圏 though.

Also, what's 死なっでも? 死んでも?

> この男ぁ炭焼で、火をじゃあじゃあ沼になげて困っから、いい暮しがされるよ うにしてけろ([source](http://www.t-bunkyo.jp/library/minwa/archives/hebimuko/text/19.html))

> また、おれも狐でも出はっていっど、だまされっど困っから早く行ってお日待 して来っから([source](http://www.t-bunkyo.jp/library/minwa/archives/ikezannzann/text/13.html))

だまされっど→騙されると? I wonder if this is [いなか言葉](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23691/30454).

Comment: 促音化 of /r/ before /k/ or /g/ seems totally unnecessary and sounds artificial to me when used outside Northern dialects in which it seems the norm.

Comment: Judging from context 死なっでも must be 死なれても.

Comment: @aguijonazo I just heard another similar utterance, but I'm not sure. 「あいつなら田中さんとこいっから」 いったから→いっから. This doesn't seem to be /r/'s 促音化. Is it related? Or should I ask about it in a separate question?

Comment: That's 田中さんのところにいるから.

Comment: @aguijonazo I need to clock myself on the head for blanking on that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used both in Kanto and Tohoku.

In Kanto, 文句あっか, 困っから, できっか, やれっか and such are rough 若者言葉 typically used by delinquent or irritated young people. It's not standard Japanese, but it's not dialectal, either. The tweet by 河野太郎 seems to be an example of this.

Similar expressions are heard also in Tohoku dialects, and in such cases, it's dialectal. Your other three quotes are examples of this.

Typical 老人語 is based on dialects in western Japan ([esp. 瀬戸内](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/91491/5010)). I feel the last two quotes are 東北弁, but not streotypical 老人語.