# Characteristics of/Sources about roujingo

Tags: resources, role-language

I'm finding various characters using ろうじんご in various works, and I'm trying to understand what are its characteristics; for example, *わし* for "I", じゃ/じゃろ as sentence-ending, のう I think like a vocative/emphasis marker (like [here](https://animecorner.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Spice-and-wolf-new-anime-key-visual.png)).

I'm trying to understand what are its characteristics and/or to find sources about it, but as for now I didn't find anything besides questions about single words (like [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38378/how-did-%E3%82%8F%E3%81%97-etc-become-stereotypical-old-people-pronouns) about わし).

So I wanted to ask what are its characteristics (if it makes sense to cover the topic as an answer here), or does anyone know sources explaining it?

Comment: Is roujingo distinct from the Japanese that was spoken when current roujingo speakers were young?

Comment: What do you mean by *characteristics*?

Comment: @sundowner what are its differences from the normal language? Like じゃ instead of だ, のう as vocative/emphasis, ぬし for "you", and so on; when I hear a character speak it's quite characteristic it, but I'm having trouble in finding those differences.

Comment: Possible reference to resource (or lack thereof) https://blog.gurPossible resource (or lack thereof). I think in most cases roujingo is made from simply replacing as per the list given in Angelos's answer.

Comment: @sundowner did you mean to send a link?

Comment: Seems like I messed up something. This is the link https://blog.gururimichi.com/entry/2018/06/20/192112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that there's [a 老人語 article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E) on the Japanese Wikipedia, discussing some of the [fictional](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E#%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E) and [real-world](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E#%E5%AE%9F%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E) instances of 老人語.  There is also [a list of characteristically 老人語 words](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E#%E8%80%81%E4%BA%BA%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7).

Answer (score 3):

Cursory answer as far as aspects I'm familiar with

~ておる、～とる for ～てる、～ている

ぞ、わ、ぞい、わい、な、のう sentence ending particles

～じゃ as copula for だ, じゃろ・じゃろう for だろ・だろう

ワシ as first-person pronoun

～ん negative rather than ～ない

～かね、～かい、～だい interrogatives

ですな、ますな、ですぞ、ますぞ occasionally in polite speech

お主 second-person pronoun

～でない directly following a verb in dictionary form as negative command

This is not an exhaustive list and many of these are not exclusively roujingo, but many of these will be indicative of a fictional character's advanced age