# Connotation of あっし as a first-person pronoun

Tags: pronouns, first-person-pronouns, pragmatics

あっし is said by [imabi](https://www.imabi.net/pronounsii.htm) to be a 1. person pronoun, derived ultimately from あたし・わたし and from the "working class dialect of Tokyo Bay" (which presumably refers to 下町言葉). [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%97) claims it to be used by "dashing males and craftsmen." (which does sound quite nice), but cites no source for this. So are these the actual connotations of あっし? How common is it?

Comment: ファンタジーなどの商人や盗賊が使うような気がします

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36794/%e3%81%82%e3%81%a1%e3%81%97-real-or-fiction/36795#36795

Comment: @l'électeur That link is super helpful, and I had ignored while searching too  - thanks!